# Necessary to duplicate table strings for local scope handling?

Tags: c, lua

I'm in a situation where a receive from Lua a table of strings. I need to accumulate the strings into an array to call an internal C function. The strings handling is local to the scope of the function (i.e., no reference is kept to the strings after the function returns).

For now, I do something like this:

```
int process_tokens(lua_State *lua)
{
    char *tokens[TOKENS_MAX];
    int ntokens = 0;

    /* assume table at top */
    while (ntokens < sizeof(tokens) / sizeof(*tokens)) {
        lua_rawgeti(lua, -1, ntokens + 1);
        if (lua_isnil(lua, -1))
            break;
        tokens[ntokens++] = luaL_checkstring(lua, -1);
        lua_pop(lua, 1);
    }

    lua_pushnumber(lua, handle_tokens(tokens, ntokens));
    return 1;
}
```

Now my question is: is it safe to *not* duplicate the strings here? I would tend to think yes, as the table that contains them can't be gc'ed until the `process_tokens()` function returns (provided it is not popped from the stack), so the strings it contains can't be too. On the other hand, I haven't found any indication as to where the pointer obtained when calling `luaL_checkstring()` actually points to (the object internals? some kind of temporary stack somewhere?).

Comment: [`lua_tolstring returns a fully aligned pointer to a string inside the Lua state.`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_tolstring)

Comment: If you know the table cannot be popped by the function and that `handle_tokens` does not modify the strings it is given in any way (including not minding getting the same pointer for multiple entries) then I believe this is safe.

Comment: In general, pointers obtained from Lua in a Lua CFunction are guaranteed to remain valid while the CFunction is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking for trouble if you are not copying the characters. The docs say, for `lua_tolstring`, "*Because Lua has garbage collection, there is no guarantee that the pointer returned by `lua_tolstring` will be valid after the corresponding value is removed from the stack.*" From your post it appears *likely* that the `char*` points to memory that will be valid for the duration of the table's lifetime, but what if the pointer is to a copy of the string that was in the Lua object? This would be surprising, but the only sure way of knowing is to look at the Lua source code.

The other reason that not copying is looking for trouble (meaning, it's ok now, but could change without notice), is that any change in your script that invalidate your assumption will lead to memory corruption without any warning. I.e., there isn't even a away for your C code to get notified when the memory pointed to by the lua_ltostring returned pointer is gc'd (and clever tricks to get notification, such as `__del` metamethod, will incur their own performance penalty).

So back to the basics of optimization: are you really concerned that the debated string copy will be a *bottleneck* in your application? Because if not, it is premature optimization, and one that could lead to a bug very laborious to isolate a year from now when you have forgotten all about this innocent looking "shortcut" :)

Comment: As to the function documentation, it's not clear to me what it implies in practice. I just read another paragraph saying `A table with weak keys allows the collection of its keys`, so its enough doubt for me. I'll go the safe way as you suggest and use a safer method for passing data around.